# I want to convert weird characters to normal in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm dealing with Java and I want to convert a String like this:

```
String = "SAYILI BUÄ�DAYLI TARIM KREDÄ° KOOPERATÄ°FÄ°"
```

to

```
SAYILI BUĞDAYLI TARIM KREDİ KOOPERATİFİ
```

as output. How can I do that?

Comment: The problem just seems to be the printing, not the value

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I'm using netbeans. I assigned the correct string value to a `String` and printed it. The same string value was in my output

Answer (score 2):

You have non printable characters in your input string

```
String str  = "SAYILI BUÄ�DAYLI TARIM KREDÄ° KOOPERATÄ°FÄ°";

Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

This will remove the non printable characters from you string 
output string will be **SAYILI BUDAYLI TARIM KRED KOOPERATF**